# Google OAuth 2.0 keep trying to callback using "http" url

Tags: django, python-3.6, google-oauth, django-allauth

I am trying to set up Google OAuth 2.0 on my homepage.
Other things seem to be well set up, but CallBack url is a problem.
I'm using "https" and also entered my callback url that starts with https in Google Oauth 2.0 console, but OAuth is still trying to callback configured with http url. How do I fix it?
If I go directly into the callback redirection url starting with https, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

Simply added it in the settings.py was solution.

ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"

That's all.